# How to view the open cursor usage for the last two hours in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone provide the query to view open cursor usage for the last two hours ..

I just want to see the open _cursor usage

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
SELECT sql_text, sql_id, fetches, rows_processed, executions, physical_read_requests, loads, cpu_time, elapsed_time
  FROM V$SQLSTATS
 WHERE last_active_time > SYSDATE - 1/12
   AND LOWER(sql_text) LIKE '%open %';
```